# regex to array in parentheses

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Hello I have question as I having issue to find a solution that works

basically in my string I have text like

```
anim(10, <-0.016, -0.006, 0.217>, <0.000, 0.000, 0.707, 0.707>, <0.016, 0.010, 0.012>);
```

what I looking to achieve it to break down this into array

something like

```
array(
0 => 'anim',
1 =>  '10',
2 => '<-0.016, -0.006, 0.217>',
3 => '<0.000, 0.000, 0.707, 0.707>',
4 => '<0.016, 0.010, 0.012>'
);
```

so I can prepare the data to send back to another script that will use it as I have special functions to make it easier for users to use.

hope someone can help as far as I managed to to break down this into 2 arrays but I need them on each line of array so I can run loops to prepare the data

Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex in `preg_match_all`:

```
(<[^>]*>|\w+)
```

**Code:**

```
$re = '/(<[^>]*>|\w+)/'; 
$str = "anim(10, <-0.016, -0.006, 0.217>, <0.000, 0.000, 0.707, 0.707>, <0.016, 0.010, 0.012>);"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xG6wN3/2)

Comment: also I do have other methods I will look how you did this do I need to have separate regex for each api like I have others like texture(9,-1,389d95a3-280a-474a-1349-514f21dc20b8) or can they all be done in one regex and put the arrays for for all of them

Comment: I believe you can use `/(<[^>]*>|[\w-]+)/` regex for both cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex.

```
preg_match_all('/<[^>]*>|\w+/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => anim
    [1] => 10
    [2] => <-0.016, -0.006, 0.217>
    [3] => <0.000, 0.000, 0.707, 0.707>
    [4] => <0.016, 0.010, 0.012>
)
```